# Create and delete github issue from QT executable

Tags: c++, ruby, git, qt

In order to make the handling of my program easier, I want to integrate the possibility of creating github issues directly in my qt program. I found out that I can list and edit the issues from the command line using `ghi`, but I do not know how to integrate the ruby gem directly in my qt program. How can I do that, or is there a better way to create new issues directly from my qt program?

Comment: If close votes or downvotes, please explain such that I am able to improve the question.

Comment: If you want to get an answer, how to improve your question, you should read some articles: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . I don't see any research attempts in your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a github API for this https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

You should implement a REST client to be able to send data , and a JSON wrapper to encode , translate the paramaters